# Make Vue Router Queries Persist at Parent Component Level

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an app where a component, `Foo`, is used as a template for a route, `app/foo`. This component has child components which are also used as templates for routes: `app/foo/bar`, `app/foo/baz`, etc.

I am binding a global `vuex` store object to the `query` property of the route so that if the object is set to, say, `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`, the url params will change to `?a=1&b=2`; and if the user changes the params to, say, `?a=0&b=0`, the object will update to be `{ a: 0, b: 0 }`. This is all working as expected.

The trouble I'm having is that, when I then route to any path under `app/foo`, I lose the route's `query` property and the url params disappear.

I can pass the `query` object dynamically like so:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'bar', query: this.$route.query });
```

But, this is quickly getting hard to maintain.

I know Vue Router provides [added life-cycle events](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), and I thought I should be able to update the query on the `Foo` component's `beforeRouteUpdate` event. I've made a few different attempts, but no dice:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  // This gives me an error saying that the query is read-only 
  to.query = from.query; 

  // This does not update the query
  this.$router.replace({ query: from.query })

  next();
},
```

#### Edit:

I also tried setting a watcher on `$route` to replace the query when the route changes. However, this causes an infinite loop:

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    this.$router.replace({ query: from.query });
  }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to make the Vue Router query persistent at a component-level?

Comment: Can you add a watcher for the route change and set the query there? see the "Reacting to Param Changes" section on [this page](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm trying this, but there are still some cases where the url params are cleared and I'm investigating why.

Comment: There is an infinite loop issue when updating the $route in the $route watcher (see edit). Even when adding certain checks (`to.path != from.path`), there is some undesirable behavior. But I'll make an answer with my current (unideal) solution based on your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @craig_h's comment, I added a watcher on `$route`:

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    if (to.path != from.path) { // to prevent an infinite loop
      this.$router.replace({ query: from.query })
    }
  }
}
```

This will work for most cases, except in the case that a component incidentally routes to the current route. In this case, the query is still lost because the `to.path` and `from.path` values are the same.

My workaround for that is to add checks to those components that might route to the current route:

```
if ((name != this.$route.name) || (params != this.$route.params)) {
  this.$router.push({ name, params });
}
```

This works but is still not ideal.